# How do I make my baking powder biscuit dough stick together?

Tags: baking

I am trying to make baking powder biscuits for strawberry shortcake.  i followed the recipe on the baking powder can and i was trying to roll them out but the dough doesn't stick together very well.  I was able to get some biscuits cut but not very easily.  Should I add more shortening or more milk?

Comment: This is quite hard to answer without more information. What is the recipe you followed? What type of biscuits, the word means different things in different parts of the world?

Answer (score 1):

If its dry adding some kinda liquid would help. Probably just needs a little more. Also helps to see the recipe. It probably said x amount of cups of flour it makes a difference if it was sifted before vers straight out of the bag. Better to go by weight instead of volume.

Comment: Key to good biscuits is getting the liquid just right. Since starting materials/humidity vary most every time, you have to develop a feel for it. Practice.

Answer (score 1):

Most biscuit doughs should be kind of wet, not dry or crumbly.  If your dough is so dry that it won't stick together you've probably used too much flour and you need to add more liquid.

One trick for cutting biscuits without altering the texture with additional flour it to place the rolled dough in the freezer for 30-45 minutes before attempting to cut it.  This is more helpful for doughs that are wet.